# How change the default Spring Boot oauth urls (/login/oauth2/code and /oauth2/authorization)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

The default URLs for starting oAuth and getting the auth code from the OAuth provider in Spring Boot are:

- `/oauth2/authorization/{providerReg}` (example: `/oauth2/authorization/azure`)
- `/login/oauth2/code/{providerReg}`

I need to change these so that they have a prefix in front of them. How do I do this?

It appears as though this is hardcoded in `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` and `DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`. Is there a way to either make those take my URLs or to make Spring Boot use my implementation instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-login-page

> To override the default login page, configure oauth2Login().loginPage() and (optionally) oauth2Login().authorizationEndpoint().baseUri().