# Spring Boot Security says PermitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I'm trying to make Keycloak work. I'm able to get the login flow to work, but not the logout and more immediately, I'm trying to add a /login route that goes to whatever the login is. If permitAll() isn't valid, I would have thought it would trigger a syntax error, but somehow, it creates this 8 mile long security chain, and blocks permitAll() in a few random inches in that chain.

To add this extra `/login`  url, I followed another person's Stackoverflow recommendation to allow an extra /login url at

[How change the default Spring Boot oauth urls (/login/oauth2/code and /oauth2/authorization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101502/how-change-the-default-spring-boot-oauth-urls-login-oauth2-code-and-oauth2-au)

Basically, I changed the RequestMatcher in `keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. I thought this was valid, but commenting it out gets rid of the error. This appears to be the offending class:

```
package com.mycompany.myapplication.configurations;

import org.keycloak.OAuth2Constants;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.AdapterStateCookieRequestMatcher;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestHeaderRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@Order(200)
public class GeneticistKeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter 
extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        final RequestMatcher customRequestMatcher =
                new OrRequestMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher(KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint.DEFAULT_LOGIN_URI),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login/**"),
                        new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER),
                        new QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher(OAuth2Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN),
                        new AdapterStateCookieRequestMatcher()
                );
        return new KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean(),customRequestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Is there some easier way to get Spring to take a URL as another way to login, then follow the normal login path?

This is a snippet of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport.permitAll(PermitAllSupport.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.PermitAllSupport.permitAll(PermitAllSupport.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.init(LogoutConfigurer.java:277)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer.init(LogoutConfigurer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:302)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:305)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to `5.7.0` Spring Security didn't support `permitAll` in `authorizeHttpRequests`.

If you upgrade to Spring Security >= `5.7.0` or Spring Boot >= `2.7.0` you should be able to add `permitAll()` when using `authorizeHttpRequests`. [This PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/10543) solved the issue.